# Trouble iterating over array using :v-for

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I am attempting to iterate over a simple array using the `v-for` directive in my Nuxt.js App.  Please see below.

```
<template>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light fixed-top">
        <nuxt-link class="navbar-brand" to="/"> 
            <img class="image nav-logo" :src="logoSrc" alt="Logo" />
        </nuxt-link>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"><span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
            <ul class="navbar-nav" >
                <li :v-for="link in links" :key="link.label">
                    {{ link.label }}
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</template>

<script>
    const linkArray = [
        {
            label: "Home",
            href: "/",
            class: ""
        },
        {
            label: "ABout",
            href: "/",
            class: ""
        },
        {
            label: "Our Menu",
            href: "/",
            class: ""
        },
        {
            label: "Contact Us",
            href: "/",
            class: "db-outline-cta"
        }
    ]

    export default {
        name: "Nav",
        data() {
            return {
                logoSrc: '/img/davidsbarlogo.png',
                links: linkArray
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

As you can see, this is my component.  I am going to be dynamically getting data for this component inside `asyncData()` later on when my cms is wired up, but I wanted to have some placeholder content.

I am repeatedly getting this error:

`ERROR  [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'label' of undefined"                                                          00:00:49`

I have tried with and wihtout the `:key` property, I know I should include one.  I am fairly new to vue, if anyone has a recommendation I would be most grateful.

Comment: just `v-for`. No need of `:` in front of `v-for`

Comment: ` 9:17  error  Elements in iteration expect to have 'v-bind:key' directives  vue/require-v-for-key` if i remove it, i get this

Comment: Then just add the :key `:key="link.label` like you have in the example(I am assuming you deleted it).

Comment: I am getting the error with or without it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<ul class="navbar-nav">
  <li v-for="link in links" :key="link.label">{{link.label}}</li>
</ul>
```

Works like a charm
https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-kapitsa-rnr4h

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```js
<li v-for="(link, index) in links" :key="index">
  {{ link.label }}
</li>
```

However, using index as key isn't the best practice (as explained in this [post](https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318)) but since there's no truly unique id in your link object, this will do.

Comment: Thank you, as it turns out.  Some linter plug-in was throwing an error.  I mistakenly thought I have to add the colon in front of v-for,  adding the key prop fixed the issue (along with uninstalling the linter)